# Segmentation Fault with array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

For the following code:

```
#include<stdatomic.h>

int *sp;

int threadFunc()
{
    int *p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        p = __atomic_load_n(&sp+i, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
        printf("Value loaded = %d from %p", *p, p);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 0;
    
    sp = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    if(sp == NULL){
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    // initialize the contiguous array pointed by sp with zero
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        memcpy((void*)sp+i, &a, sizeof(int));
    }
    
    // call the following function on different thread
    threadFunc();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault in `threadFunc()`. The program prints correctly for `i=0`, but gives a segmentation fault for all `i > 0`. Where is it that I am going wrong?

Comment: You don't need to cast to void*. (and there is no array of pointers present in your program)

Comment: That `int main{` looks wonky - what compiler are you using? If this is supposed to be standard C, please test to compile your code before posting.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry about that. Fixed it!

Comment: @RestingPlatypus: No, you didn't.

Comment: Please put code up that you actually can compile yourself. If this actually compiles for you, please mention what compiler (and options) you are using.

Comment: `__atomic_load_n(&sp+i` looks very wrong due to operator precedence.

Comment: `&sp+i` is not what you want. It takes the address of `sp` and adds `i` to it. But there are no other pointer after the single one.

Comment: ... there are also a number of header files missing ...

Comment: What happens if you replace the `&sp+i` in `threadFunc` with `sp+i` like you have in `main`?

Comment: `(void*)sp+i` attempts pointer arithmetic on a void pointer.

Comment: This sounds glib, but I think you've got a segmentation fault because you _don't_ have an array of pointers. You've got a single pointer, `sp`, that points to an array of 10 integers

Comment: @TimRandall : that was mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @thebusybee I tried using `&(sp+i)`, the compiler gave me the following error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand.

Comment: @wildplasser I see and yes, you are right.  I actually need an array of pointers where each element points to an int.

Comment: @thebusybee Why is this question closed? Are there still details missing or can it be reopened?

Comment: IMHO your question still needs debugging details and some evidence of your own attempt to find the error. Beside this, it is a simple misunderstanding of the pointer concept on your side, which was addressed in multiple comments and answers. However, there is an answer and you accepted it. Do you want more answers, or why do you want it reopened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to supply a pointer to the object here:

```
_atomic_load_n(&sp+i, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
```

This is not the correct thing:

```
&sp + i
```

The above takes the address of `sp` and adds `i`, pointing ... somewhere where you have no `int*` stored. Also, you want to load from an `int`, not an `int*`.

A fix would be:

```
int threadFunc() {
    int p;                                 // not an int*
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        p = atomic_load_explicit(sp + i, memory_order_seq_cst); // not &sp + i
        // or:  p = __atomic_load_n(sp + i, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
        printf("Value loaded = %d\n", p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>(I just replaced the call with the corresponding standard call)</sup>

Also, use `memset` to set what you allocated:

```
memset(sp, 0, sizeof(int) * 10);
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pcd4rjasc)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I tried a similar approach, but I was setting something like `int **p` followed by `p = &sp` and then replacing `&sp+i` by `p[i]`, and that didn't work.

Comment: @RestingPlatypus You're welcome. I guess you may have made an addition to the pointer erroneously so that it ends up pointing out of bounds. All the `**`'s makes it tricky.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main
```

will not compile.  The minimum signature of the `main` prototype is:

```
int main(void);
```

Another problem in the code shown is incorrect use of memcpy().  It does not require a loop use:

Change this:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        memcpy((void*)sp+i, &a, sizeof(int));
   }
```

to this

```
memset(sp, 0, 10* sizeof(int));
```

Finally, int the expression:

```
int *p;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    p = __atomic_load_n(&sp+i, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    printf("Value loaded = %d from %p", *p, p);
}
```

`p` is a pointer, but it points to some location that is not yet owned by your process.  Writing to it is undefined behavior, and likely the cause of your seg-fault.